# NHibernate IInterceptor composition

Tags: nhibernate, lambda, interceptor

We have a project that uses an Interceptor object to tell NHibernate to do some general works before saving an entity.This interceptor has a single task to do.Now there's another task that should be added to this interceptor (NHibernate doesn't support multiple interceptors) but I don't want to make this interceptor complicated instead I would like to use composition pattern that will manage all registered interceptors.something like this :

```
public bool Onload(object entity,object id,object[] state,string propertyNames,IType[] types_
{
var result=false;
foreach(var interceptor in _registeredInterceptors)
result=result || interceptor.OnLoad(entity,id,state,propertyNames,types);
return result;
}

public bool OnFlushDirty(object entity,object id,object[] state,string propertyNames,IType[] types_
{
var result=false;
foreach(var interceptor in _registeredInterceptors)
result=result || interceptor.OnFlushDirty(entity,id,state,propertyNames,types);
return result;
}
```

by looking at this code I realized that there might be a better way preventing me from repeating myself.
the question is can I make this code more simpler and abstract using Lambda expressions and yield keyword?

Comment: I mentioned Lambda expressions because I'd like to use closures so I don't have to create individual delegates for each set of methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it could look like this:

```
public bool Execute(IList<IInterceptor> interceptors, Func<IInterceptor, bool> func)
{
    bool result = false;
    foreach (IInterceptor interceptor in interceptors)
    {
        result = result || func(interceptor);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And in the parent interceptor:

```
public bool Onload(object entity, object id, object[] state, string propertyNames, IType[] types_
{
    return Execute(_registeredInterceptors, x => x.OnLoad(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
}

public bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, object id, object[] state, string propertyNames, IType[] types_
{
    return Execute(_registeredInterceptors, x => x.OnFlushDirty(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
}
```

**Update**

If you want the result type to be generic you could do it like this:

```
public static T Execute<T>(IList<IInterceptor> interceptors, Func<IInterceptor, T> func)
{   
    T result = default(T);
    foreach (IInterceptor interceptor in interceptors)
    {
        // your logic based on type T
    }

    return T;
}
```

Execution of the generic version would look exactly the same as of the `bool` one because of `Type inference`.

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Well sort of :) but  still I have to write a separate execute method for each return value(object,void,int).I am thinking is there anyway so I could make a generic method for all the scenarios.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the only problem with this *generic* version is that you would need to find a generalization for all methods that you are planning to implement but I guess you already figured that one out

Comment: Well I gave it a try but I couldn't realize how I could cast a generic type to a bool.I tried if(typeof(T)==typeof(bool)) result=(bool) result || (bool)func; but I am getting compiler error any clues ?

Comment: You can cast a generic type to `boolean` by using `(bool)Convert.ChangeType(interceptor, typeof (bool))` or `Convert.ToBoolean(func(interceptor))`